# What is the most useful rationality criterion of surfaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

The motivation for this question is that I would like to extract some information from derived category of surfaces to conclude the rationality of surface. There is a well known rationality criterion called Castelnuovo's criterion. I recall it as follows: Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and if $q:=h^1(O_X)=0, P_2(X)=h^0(2K_X)=0$, then $X$ is rational surface. Where $K_X$ is canonical divisor of $X$. I found that $q=0$ is somewhat relatively easier to obtain from the derived category: say if $D^b(X)$ admits a full exceptional collection or stronger assumption, say if $D^b(X)$ admits a full exceptional collection of line bundles, then, $q=h^1(O_X)=0$. On the other hand, I found $h^0(2K_X)=0$ is really hard to obtain. There is some very special case where I can obtain such equality, say if a surface admit a cyclic strong exceptional collection of line bundles, then I can conclude that $-K_X$ is strictly effective by some techniques. Then $-2K_X$ is strictly effective, thus $h^0(2K_X)=0$. Thus, I can conclude that $X$ is rational surface. But in general, there are many rational surfaces with $-K_X$ not effective at all. So in general, I do not expect such method will work.

There is another classical way to conclude $X$ is rational, it uses the classification of surfaces: one can first obtain that $X$ is uniruled, or equivalently, the kodaira dimension $kod(X)=-\infty$, then $X$ is a ruled surface and $q=0$ implies that $X$ is rational. For example, in the work of M.Brown and I.Shipman: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3918

They proved that the existence of full strong exceptional collection of line bundles on $X$ implies that rationality of surfaces. Basically, they showed that there exists some free rational curve on $X$ ($C^2\geq 0, p_a(C)=0$), then $X$ is covered by rational curves(or equivalently, $kod(X)=-\infty$), together with $q=0$, the $X$ is rational surface. It looks like this way of showing the rationality is more flexible, it uses some techniques coming from higher dimensional birational geometry, say the concept of free rational curves.

Also, of course the classification results for rational surfaces: any rational surface is blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2, \mathbb{F}_n,n\neq 1$ is also used sometimes. In our recent work: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03972

we showed the existence of cyclic strong exceptional collection of line bundles imply the surfaces is weak del pezzo ($-K_X$ is big and nef). We used the alternative definition of weak del pezzo, i.e: it is either $\mathbb{F}_0,\mathbb{F}_2$ or blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at most $8$ points in so called almost general position. We can extract information from cyclic strong exceptional collection of line bundles to showed this.

So my question is
**Do you know some other way(criterion) to conclude that $X$ is a rational surface?** Since I am not an expert in higher dimensional algebraic geometry, I am very curious to know some techniques from there (because maybe we can understand things deeper by observing things from general perspective). For example, some concepts like uniruled, unirational, rational connected might be very different from each other in higher dimensional case, but in the case of surfaces, maybe they coincide or very close to each other, then maybe some criterion of them in higher dimensional geometry will help.

Comment: To conclude that $q = 0$ it is enough to know that there is one exceptional object of nonzero rank.